# How to make Symfony Console run Native terminal command?

Tags: symfony

How can I run native `terminal command (e.g: bower)` with [symfony/console](https://github.com/symfony/Console)?

I had `bower` installed in my mac, and can be run from `console`. But now i need symfony/console to be able run my native terminal command (e.g: bower).

How to do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can use PHP's [`exec`](http://php.net/exec) function. Or, if you want to have more controll of it and read the result in a nice way, you can use the [Symfony Process component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html):

```
exec('bower');
// or it's shortcut
`bower`;

// or the Process component
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$bower = new Process('bower');
$bower->run();

// ... other nice things, like $bower->isSuccesful(), ->getOutput() & more
```